# Undesirable auto incrementing minutes

Tags: php

The Code:

```
$months = array("January", "February" .......); // Up to December
foreach ($months As $month) {
  $date_ranges_from[] = date('F d, Y H:m:s', strtotime("$month 1 midnight"));
}
print_r($date_ranges_from);
```

The Undesired output:

```
// Notice that the minutes are auto-incremented
Array
(
 [0] => January 01, 2015 00:01:00
 [1] => February 01, 2015 00:02:00
 [2] => March 01, 2015 00:03:00
 [3] => April 01, 2015 00:04:00
 [4] => May 01, 2015 00:05:00
 [5] => June 01, 2015 00:06:00
 [6] => July 01, 2015 00:07:00
 [7] => August 01, 2015 00:08:00
 [8] => September 01, 2015 00:09:00
 [9] => October 01, 2015 00:10:00
 [10] => November 01, 2015 00:11:00
 [11] => December 01, 2015 00:12:00
)
```

The Desired output:

```
// The time should always be 00:00:00
Array
(
 [0] => January 01, 2015 00:00:00
 [1] => February 01, 2015 00:00:00
 [2] => March 01, 2015 00:00:00
 [3] => April 01, 2015 00:00:00
 [4] => May 01, 2015 00:00:00
 [5] => June 01, 2015 00:00:00
 [6] => July 01, 2015 00:00:00
 [7] => August 01, 2015 00:00:00
 [8] => September 01, 2015 00:00:00
 [9] => October 01, 2015 00:00:00
 [10] => November 01, 2015 00:00:00
 [11] => December 01, 2015 00:00:00
)
```

The problem:
I don't know why the minutes gets also incremented when I statically put it as midnight. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause You were incrementing month with each loop `H:m:s` which should be `H:i:s`

Within php `date` function `m` stands for `month` and `i` for `minutes`

```
$date_ranges_from[] = date('F d, Y H:m:s', strtotime("$month 1 midnight"));
                                  //^^ m stands for month
```

should be

```
$date_ranges_from[] = date('F d, Y H:i:s', strtotime("$month 1 midnight"));
                                  //^^ i stands for minutes
```

Comment: Oh damn it. I'm so clumsy hahahhahahhahah